# Java - System.currentTimeMillis(); Not Returning Difference

Tags: java

For some reason I am getting a consistent 3600 returned by the function:

```
private static long getCountdownLeft() {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedMillis = now - initialTime; //difference of current 'current' time
    long millisLeft = secondsOfGame * 1000 - elapsedMillis;
    return millisLeft/1000;
}

public static void Main(String[] args ) {
     System.out.println("Time is " + getCountdownLeft());
}

private static int secondsOfGame = 3600;
private static long initialTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

This is event driven. I expect to see a difference in time everytime I invoke the function. I just use main to show that I am invoking it.

Comment: and also you are reffering non-static context from a staic context. So  theres another compilation issue. I understand that the 'Main' is just for demo, but try to have working code here to make it easier for those who want to help you :)

Comment: Side note, `Main`? Is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: w/e on main! And I apologize for my laziness.

Comment: you might really want to check your code for correctness. I'm sure that the code that you posted right now cannot be executed as is.

Comment: Mind showing how you are invoking getCountdownLeft()? Maybe there is some bug in the invocation code. Also you can try to log "now" and "initialTime" in the function for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

This is most probably because the `elapsedMillis` is coming as zero. I would suggest using `System.nanoTime()` for calculating elapsed time.

I'm not so sure how your code works (as is posted right now), but something like this might work. Note that you need to add your logic for computation, this is just a sample:

```
public class TimeTest {

    private long startTime;

    public TimeTest(){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
    }

    public void computeTimeDifference(){
        long currentTime = System.nanoTime();
        long elapsedTime = currentTime - startTime;

        System.out.println("Difference: "+elapsedTime+ "ns");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TimeTest().computeTimeDifference();
    }
}
```

Comment: Since system.currentTimeMillis is always the 'current' time whenever i use it..wouldnt that make it > 0?

Comment: You set a new current gameTime each time you run your program, and then you immediately call getCountdownLeft(gameTime). The approximate elapsed time is 0.

Comment: agree with @irrelephant. the time difference between the invocation of the method comes to zero, hence you see no difference

Comment: Sorry, the gameTime needed to be a GLOBAL VARIABLE INITIALIZED - Edited.

Answer (score 0):

Your code will consume little time before invoke getCountdownLeft. try update this code :

```
    public static void Main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long gameTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); // pass the current time
    Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000); // sleep one second before invoke getCountdownLeft
    System.out.println("Time is " + getCountdownLeft(gameTime));
}
```

Comment: its actually a callback which calls back every 4 seconds, i thot that I would omit that for some reason

Answer (score 0):

Hey I have just added print statements for prev, new and elapsed variables. The values are

> previous time 1343882409054
>
> present time 1343882409054
>
> elapsed time 0
>
> Time is 3600

So your millisLeft will always be 3600 .

But if you try using

> System.nanoTime()

the values are,

> previous time 519222175869357
>
> present time 519222175923421
>
> elapsed time 54064
>
> Time is 3545

So you have to be more granular here and consider using System.nanoTime().

Comment: Answer is posted. Thank you for your interest.